# .bash_profile isn't sourced during logon

Tags: linux, bash, gentoo

I've declared an alias in `.bashrc` file located in my home directory. Export of `PS1` environment variable has been added to this file too.

```
# /etc/skel/.bashrc
#
# This file is sourced by all *interactive* bash shells on startup,
# including some apparently interactive shells such as scp and rcp
# that can't tolerate any output.  So make sure this doesn't display
# anything or bad things will happen !


# Test for an interactive shell.  There is no need to set anything
# past this point for scp and rcp, and it's important to refrain from
# outputting anything in those cases.
if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
        # Shell is non-interactive.  Be done now!
        return
fi


# Put your fun stuff here.
alias ll='ls -l'
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

However, these changes don't have any effect. I don't have the alias declared in the file after logon. `$PS1` isn't affected too. AFAIK user's `.bashrc` script is sourced by `.bash_profile` script located in the user's home directory. So I've added the following line to my .bash_profile for testing purposes:

```
echo hello > ~/test.txt
```

Here is full content of my `.bash_profile` file:

```
# /etc/skel/.bash_profile

# This file is sourced by bash for login shells.  The following line
# runs your .bashrc and is recommended by the bash info pages.
echo hello > ~/test.txt
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

`test.txt` doesn't appear in my home directory after logon. It seems that the `.bash_profile` isn't called during logon.

How to set the system to take user's `.bash_profile` into account?

Comment: Is your shell a login shell? It means for example logging in from a Linux console (Ctrl+Alt+F1), through ssh: `ssh localhost` or `su -l $USER` etc.

Comment: @pabouk I boot my system in runlevel 3 and then start GUI with `startx` manually if needed. So immediately after boot I definitely have login shell. However, there isn't any sign (alias, environment variable, test.txt file) that my `.bash_profile` script is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, **dsumsky**, for your answer.

Indeed, `.bashrc` is definitely sourced when I run `bash` manually. This put in my mind the question "What shell is set as login shell for my user?". It was `/bin/sh`. The problem has disappeared after I replaced it with `/bin/bash` despite the fact that `/bin/sh` symlink is targeted at `/bin/bash`.

Comment: When you call `bash` as `sh` it runs in Bourne shell compatibility mode and it will not source `~/.bash_profile`. It will source `~/.profile` at the first place instead.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try to run bash by hand? Simply

```
bash
```

for interactive shell which will use `.bashrc` file and

```
bash -l
```

for login shell to test `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` files.

Additionally, you can try to trace system calls of the bash process with strace utility and to check wether configuration files where opened at least

```
strace -f -e open bash
strace -f -e open bash -l
```